# Error while converting gridview with paging into excel

Tags: asp.net

I am using the following code to convert gridview to ms-excel format. The problem is this if i use following code one 1st page is converted into ms-ecxel

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    string file1 = TextBox1.Text + ".xls";
    string attachment = string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", file1);
    this.EnableViewState = false;

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {

        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

and if add these two lines to my code i"ll get blank ms-excel sheet

```
         GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        this.Emp_Wrklog();
```

please do the needful changes in my code so that i can cnvert my gridview having paging into excel. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use `EPPlus` library or something like that for manipulating excel files.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/